# Cannot import modules of parent packages inside child packages

Tags: python

I have a parent package that has 2 child packages. It looks like this

```
backend
   __init__.py
   conf.py
   db.py
   connections.py
   /api
      __init__.py
      register.py
      api.py
   /scheduled
      __init__.py
      helpers.py
```

`All the __init__.py files are empty.`

The code in `backend/connections.py` and `backend/conf.py` is being used by modules in both packages `api` and `scheduled`.

in register.py i have code like

```
from backend.conf import *
from backend.connections import *
```

Now when i do `python register.py`
i get this error

```
ImportError: No module named backend.conf
```

Also when i changed `from backend.conf import *` to `from ..conf import *` or `from .. import conf` i get this error

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

What i understand by the above error is that python is not treating the above folders as packages. But i have `__init__.py` in all the folders. What is wrong?

Comment: @MrE why `connections` is not a module? all the `__init__.py` files are empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run `python register.py`, your `backend/register.py` file is used as the `__main__` module of the program, rather than as a module within the `backend` package.  Further more, the Python import path will not automatically include the directory containing the `backend` directory, which is probably the cause of your problems.

One option that might work is to run your program as `python -m backend.register` from the top level directory of your project (or set `PYTHONPATH` so this module can be found).  This will search for the script on the normal import path, and then run it as the main program.

Comment: @lovesh: In a nutshell, you can't put a main module in a subpackage.

Comment: As I said in my answer, you can if you start your program with `python -m`.

Comment: Exactly -- a good reason not to try it -- maybe I should have said "..you _shouldn't_ put a main module in a subpackage."